# Odd output allocating 2D char Matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, char, adjacency-matrix

working on a small project and I'm trying to make a 2D array of chars. I've done it with ints before and tried to go off of that example, but it seems like I'm running into an issue that I don't understand.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
adjMatrix = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * dimensions);

for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++)
    adjMatrix[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (dimensions + 2));

for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < (dimensions + 2); j++)
        adjMatrix[i][j] = '0';
```

Here is my display function:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (dimensions + 2); j++)
            printf("%s ", &(adjMatrix[i][j]));

        printf("\n");
    }
```

And this is my output

```
000000 00000 0000 000 00 0 
000000 00000 0000 000 00 0 
000000 00000 0000 000 00 0 
000000 00000 0000 000 00 0
```

Could anyone explain to me why it's showing that way and give any advice as to how to make it just a single '0' in each slot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could anyone explain to me why it's showing that way and give any advice as to how to make it just a single '0' in each slot?

This is, because you advise to print a string and not a single character.

Change your code to:

```
printf("%c ", adjMatrix[i][j]);
```

Note, `adjMatrix[i]` points to an array of single characters and an array of characters is a string. Further this is undefined behavior, because you don't 0 terminate the "string".

`&adjMatrix[i][0]` is a pointer to `'0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0'`,
`&adjMatrix[i][1]` is a pointer to `'0' '0' '0' '0' '0'`,
`&adjMatrix[i][2]` is a pointer to `'0' '0' '0' '0'`,
...

Comment: *facepalm* I feel like a dummy. Small mistake, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

> Could anyone explain to me why it's showing that way

The short answer is "undefined behavior" because

1) you try to print something which is **not** a string using `%s` (which requires a string, i.e. a char array that contain the zero-termination `'\0'`).

2) you read out of bounds as printf with %s will keep reading until it sees a string termination.

Due to undefined behavior it can be said that it makes no sense to guess about what is going on.

If we do that anyway, it may be something like:

You use 6 columns and initialize them to '0' so that the memory is

```
 '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0'
```

and we can't tell what is after the last '0'. By "luck" it seems that the next memory location happens to hold a string termination. Like:

```
 '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '\0'
                          ^^
                          A guess...
```

Now you print it as a string using `%s` (and adding a space).

The first time you pass a pointer to the first '0'.

```
 '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '\0'
  ^
  pointer
```

so it will give you a print of 6 '0' (and the space).

Then you move the pointer to the right and call printf again

```
 '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '\0'
      ^
      pointer
```

so it will give you a print of 5 '0'

The next loops will give 4 '0' then 3 then 2 then 1 and you end up with

```
000000 00000 0000 000 00 0
```

But again - since it's really undefined behavior, this is just guessing. Anything could have happened.